# UIElement.InvalidateArrange() and UpdateLayout() Alternatives in Uno Platforms

Tags: c#, uno-platform

It seems the Uno Platform doesn't support InvalidateArrange() and UpdateLayout() methods within UIElement. When building an existing UWP project warnings such as below may appear:

```
...\Source\UserControls\View\TableView.xaml.cs(743,17,743,39): warning Uno0001: Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.InvalidateArrange() is not implemented in Uno
...\Source\UserControls\View\TableView.xaml.cs(745,17,745,34): warning Uno0001: Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.UpdateLayout() is not implemented in Uno
```

What is the suggested alternative? How should a UIElement be invalidated and then updated in Uno? I note that InvalidateMeasure() does appear to be implemented.

In UWP it was necessary to manually invalidate both measure and arrange and then force an update or glitches would occur. Whether or not this is a UWP internal issue is probably not important here.

Answer (score 0):

While those methods are not yet implemented on all platforms, invoking them anyways is safe.

You may need still to invoke `UIElement.InvalidateMeasure()` for this to work properly on Uno.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your feedback. If I can invoke InvalidateArrange() and UpdateLayout() without throwing not implemented exceptions I won't bother to change this code for Uno Platform. InvalidateMeasure() is already called with InvalidateArrange() in the code base as well.